# Updating Windows form rapidly in Windows CE 6.0 multi-threaded program (.NET 3.5 Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm new to programming in Windows CE 6.0 on an ARM-based 32-bit processor using C# and .NET 3.5 Compact Framework. I'm supposed to be creating a user interface that shows information coming from different threads in a heavily multi-threaded program (think of an update to a status board or to a game loop). Using tricks I've done on more typical Windows desktop applications, I launch my Windows form on its own thread and update the appearance in a Paint event handler.

I've got an API that the other threads can call (it's thread-safe, as far as I can tell - locks on shared data items, etc.), and the calls that update the data structures then trigger an Invalidate() on my Windows form. My expectation is that sometime (soon, hopefully) my form gets told to repaint and it updates the screen with the latest data that's been provided.

Only I'm not getting as rapid a refresh rate as I would expect. I even put in a timer that triggered Invalidate() 30 times per second and I didn't get more frequent updates, even in a simplified setup. In a more vicious setup, where I launch a thread that's basically doing `while (true) {}`, then my Paint event NEVER gets called (not a surprise there, really, but still...). So I'm not sure whether I'm not understanding something about the environment my program is running in (VERY possible), or if there are some other things I need to account for in Windows CE that I'm not aware of currently. I've spent a lot of time with Google and reading lots of SO responses and various blogs, etc. My display refresh is still slower than I need.

I realize this is somewhat vague. What I'm trying to understand is if there are some tricks that I need to understand about Windows CE 6.0 and it's implementation of multi-threading and Windows Forms, etc., to see if there are ways to improve the refresh rate of my form painting (and ideally ensure that it gets called at least once a second, for example).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps but consider this:

Do not run threads without a sleep inside. DO/While(TRUE) is bad. Windows CE is multithreaded but the time slices given to a thread depend on co-operation of all threads giving the OS the chance to yield to another thread.

Do not use invalidate or refresh on the whole form. If you have a list of informations to display from different threads only let a thread update its portion of the GUI.

You may use SendMessage to update the GUI instead of PostMessage (in contrast to use events/delegates). SendMessage will block until msg is processed, so use it only from background thread. But SendMessage will ensure the fastest update on the GUI thread (if used for portion of screen).

You may even decouple the background threads and the GUI using a message queue. So post all updates of threads into the queue and on the GUI peek the message to make changes to the GUI. Again, do not run background threads without a Sleep or WaitObject inside.

You may use invalidate/refresh to update the GUI, but use it on single controls only. In example: you have a number of labels showing thread values, when a thread value is to be updated then only invalidate/refersh the label assigned to the thread value and not the whole form.

You may sync GUI updates and threads using events, so a thread is blocked until the GUI fires the event to unblock, for example when the GUI has finished processing the thread's update message.

Note that Windows CE is not a real-time OS. It uses co-operative Multitasking. A single thread can consume nearly all processor time.

Possibly doing a win32 API app will enhance speed as Compact Framework code (IL, GarbageCollection etc) is slower than native code.